# How to make a custom button provide haptic feedback

Tags: application-development, qml

I've got a custom round button that is derived from [Ubuntu.Components.AbstractButton](https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.10/Ubuntu.Components.AbstractButton). Looking at the documentation, it states that:

> All components deriving from this class support haptic feedback out of the box.

However, my button does not provide haptic feedback when pressed. How exactly can it be enabled for custom buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Abstract Buttons do indeed come with haptic feedback out of the box and does not require any special properties to enable it. It sounds like you are experiencing a bug. Perhaps if you can add the code of your custom round button, one can confirm and check if it works on our end or not.